# How to video call between person and video use WebRTC?

Tags: java, webrtc, opentok

I'm trying to create a function that instructs the user to use the App by having the user make a call with a video tutorial.
Video tutorials will be recorded in advance and stored in the directory: "/opt/video-tutorial/Tutorial.mp4".

How can I do this using WebRTC? My server is written in Java, so is there a way to do this?

Comment: You need to have a publisher to share a video file into a session. Server components cannot act as publishers on Opentok, but you can use the Linux SDK on a server to achieve this.

Here is a JS implementation if you would like to use the browser: https://github.com/opentok/opentok-web-samples/tree/main/Publish-Video

It is worth noting that publishing this video will incur costs on your side so it will be cheaper (and easier) to simulate a call and use the built-in video player on your platform of choice to play the video

Comment: @abdulajet Thank, I have seen the example you sent, however there is 1 drawback. It's a video that doesn't auto play when i run the project
I've been looking for a way to deal with this but there doesn't seem to be a way. Is there any other alternative to Publish Video?

Comment: which platform are you trying to autoplay on? web?

Comment: No, I want play video in linux :((